# How to display the therotical transmission range of the vehicle, when it become a cluster head?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I know that in the ned file, the following line can display a circle representing the transmission range of the vehicle.

```
@display("p=1025,1025;is=s;r=300");
```

How can I disable/enable this code from the cc file? Or is there another way to do it from the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ code of your module use the following commands:

- to show a range:

  ```
  getDisplayString().setTagArg("r", 0, 300);
  ```
- to disable showing a range:

  ```
  getDisplayString().removeTag("r");
  ```

References:

1. [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual - Changing Display Strings at Runtime](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:graphics:changing-displaystrings-at-runtime)
2. [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual - Appendix G: Display String Tags](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#cha:display-strings)

Comment: thanks, @JerzyD. for the solution. it worked for me when I appended findHost() to it.